# Gracefully handle zero values in bar charts with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a clock with d3 by making a bar chart updates as each second passes.

Typically I would set my yScale like so:

```
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain(maximumTime)
          .range([svgHeight, 0]);
```

but this will leave an a blank bar at each new minute, hour, and day. To solve for this I've set the to go to `-1` so something is always displayed, even when the value is zero.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(maximumTime)
      .range([svgHeight, -1]);
```

Is there a more graceful way that I can display zero values?

Full example in a CodePen: http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/vEWZXb

Comment: You could add the actual number to the bars.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff what do you mean?

Comment: Have a number that shows the value.